# PHP parsing json failing

Tags: php, json

I am making a gaming panel with php where I need to read from a json api I have been reading on how to do this I need to get the value in the json api of banned

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$test = $steam->steamid;
$url = 'https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/' . $test;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$api = json_decode($json);

echo $api->banned;
```

After running this I am receiving 
Notice:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$banned in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14
```

It should come back as a true or false value

I can view the array using var_dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP error is pretty straight forward, there is no property named `banned` ($api->banned).

So, looking at the `json` response, the `banned` property is inside the `response` property, so your echo should be:

```
echo $api->response->banned;
```